# json_decode equals to null

Tags: php, json, curl

How do I get better error messaging to debug my problem?

```
<?php

// Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init('http://api.mirai.so/external/test');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
));

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
    echo "Error!";
}
else {
$result = var_dump(json_decode($response, TRUE));
echo $result;
}
?>
```

What it should do is get the data from the .json file and echo them.

Comment: `var_dump` returns null.

Comment: You might want to check the status of json_last_error() http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php and curl_error. var_dump should be printing the output of decoding the json object. If you don't see anything there's probably an upstream error in your system.

Comment: What happens if you run the api in a browser? What response/error log do you get?

Comment: @jbrahy Tried it I am getting - Syntax error, malformed JSON.

Comment: Goto http://jsonlint.com/ and check if the JSON is valid and modify it until it is valid. then this should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the curl options and set ini user_agent. Tested and works.

```
<?php
ini_set('user_agent','MSIE 4\.0b2;'); // this is required. otherwise you'll get a 401

// Setup cURL
$url = "http://api.mirai.so/external/test";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch); // Send the request

// Check for errors
IF ($response === FALSE) {
    echo "Error!";
}ELSE{
  $result = json_decode($response, true);
  die("<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>"); // prettier
}
?>
```

Comment: echo() the response without decoding it and take a look at the formatting. If it's not too large post it in the original post. Your JSON is not formatted correctly.

Comment: I am now getting 400 Bad Request cloudflare-nginx!

Comment: try `DIE($response);`

Comment: And also below it I am getting - Syntax error, malformed JSON

Comment: I am again getting 400 Bad Request cloudflare-nginx but this time without - Syntax error, malformed JSON

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96730/discussion-between-geotsak-and-brian).

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning result of `var_dump` function (which returns `null`) to `$result` variable.
Why do you do this?

You should assign `json_decode` result to `$result`:

```
$result = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

Comment: I am getting, after running json_last_error() - Syntax error, malformed JSON

Comment: So - `var_dump($response)`, what is it?